# How to run a jquery code by scrolling for once

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a jquery code that I've indicated below. These codes run, When I start scrolling (I mean when the height of scroll is more than 100)

But I want to run just for once, immediately after height of 100, and not to be run more than once.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 ){
  //some codes...
 }
});
```

How can I do this? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as your condition is met, unbind the scroll handler:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 ){
        //Kill the handler
        $(window).off("scroll");

        //some codes...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use
   `$(window).unbind('scroll');` 
When you enter first time

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 ){
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
    //some codes...

   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the scroll event to `$(window)`, then when `scrollTop() > 100`, execute your action then unbind the scroll event from `$(window)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('body').prepend('Scroll top > 100');
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
      }
   });
});
```

```css
body { min-height: 1000px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://codepen.io/pen/

Answer (score 0):

ok this can be done with the help of global variable or flag  in order to see the effect first put lots of data into the page so that you can see vertical scroll.

```
<script>
var flag = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if (flag == 0) {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    alert('1st time');
                    flag = 1;
                }
            } else if (flag == 1) {
                alert('second time and u can comment this alert');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The .off() function will stop the function from firing after the first time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('scroll.myEvent', function() {
        if ($(document.body.scrollTop > 100))
        {
             $(window).off('scroll.myEvent');
       alert('fired');
        }

       });
});

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2k3s9jx8/
```